# Problems when trying to connect to a router wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, router, internet-connection, network-adapter

**The situation** - At my girlfriend's parents' place there are six Windows 7 devices that are wired or wireless connected to a router: 3 dekstops and 3 laptops. There are also several smartphones using the router. The router is secured with WPA2 (AES).

**The problem** - We never had any problems with the router for over a year. But recently - about 3 weeks ago - my girlfriend's laptop (HP) and my laptop (ASUS) started to develop problems while trying to connect to the router. The router has stopped showing up from the network list. Sometimes it comes back and shows up, but then it keeps saying something along the lines of "Could not connect", and not long after that it dissapears again.

The range of the router is not the problem here, because we experience the same when we sit next to the router. Sometimes, if we are lucky, and waited a long time (10-15 minutes) without using the laptop for anything, the laptop will eventually succesful connect to the router.

**The attempts** - Of course, the Window 7 troubleshooter. We tried troubleshooting the connection problems and the wireless network adapter, but no luck. We also reset the router enough times to know that's not helping either. Here's the full list of things we tried, but did not help:

- Running the Windows 7 troubleshooter
- Resetting the router (more than once)
- Setting the router settings to factory defaults
- Disconnecting all other devices except one laptop
- Applying a system restore
- Trying static/dynamic IP/DNS - *Dynamic is better, right?*
- Enabling/disabling IPv6 - *Should I keep IPv6 disabled?*
- Running the command: `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`
- Running the command: `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`
- Updating/reïnstalling wireless adapter drivers

**The tests** - To help finding the core of the problem, we tested the following:

- Plugging an ethernet cable in the router and in our laptops - **worked fine**
- Connecting someone else's laptop to the router (wireless) - **worked fine**
- Connecting our laptops to someone else's router - **worked fine**

**The router** - This information might be relevant:

- Router model: Sitecom 300N Wireless Router
- Router hardware: version 01

The DCHP Server's IPs range from 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200. Router settings:

- Wireless channel: 12
- Channel bandwidth: 20/40 MHz
- Extension channel: 8
- Preamble type: Long
- 802.11g protection: Disabled
- UPnP: Enabled

**The laptops** - If you are wondering about our laptops:

- My laptop model: ASUS Pro64JQ
- Girlfriend's laptop: HP Pavillion G6
- OS: Both Windows 7 Professional x64 - *with Service Pack 1*
- My wireless adapter: Atheros AR9285
- AdHoc 11n: Enabled

**The question** - Does anyone have experienced the same problems as I do? Or does someone know how to solve this? Are there more tricks I can try, or settings I should change?

**Note** - Our laptops are not slow or old. My laptop is 1.5 years old, and the other laptop is just 5 months old. I know how to keep laptops clean and I'm pretty sure both laptops are not bloated with useless software.

Comment: What channel is the router on?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - The router is on channel 12. It's extension channel, don't know what that is, is on 8. If you want to know more, see the edit I made to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this might sound weird, but I fixed by doing things I've tried before. <strike>I don't really know what fixed it in the end, but it's fixed. :)</strike>

To the people who are interested, this is what I did (probably):

I removed and reïnstalled the drivers again, but this time a different version. However I installed the latest version right after that. In the meanwhile **I reset the router to factory defaults**, and disabled my LAN Ethernet Adapter. I've disabled/enabled my WiFi adapter a couple of times, and restarted my laptop for about twice. Somehow this removed all saved wireless networks from my laptop, and now I have to fill in every WEP/AES key again. That sucks, because I use my laptop at a lot of places, but now it works again. :)

**Edit**: After I fixed the issues with my laptop, the issues with my girlfriend's laptop were gone too. *So it was probably resetting the router to factory defaults that did it.* It wasn't the first time I tried that, but maybe I did it wrong earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Did the router reset change your channel bandwidth setting from 20/40 to 20 only? I found changing to 20 only fixed a couple of constantly dropped connections for me, improved speed too, despite logic dictating otherwise. There's plenty of articles describing why 20/40 isn't generally a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the channel on the router.  If it's on Auto, try something like 3 or 8.  Channels 1, 6, and 11 are the most commonly used so it's better to distance yourself from those.

Another settings on some routers is the channel width.  Sometimes you'll see 10 MHz, 20 MHz, or 40 MHz.  The higher the setting, the faster the throughput but the stronger the signal needs to be to work well.

There are wireless networking tools available also for PC, Mac, and mobile devices that can help you get more info on your wireless "environment" that might help.

If changing the channel doesn't help, it could be overheating.  Routers, like computers, will lower their power consumption when they get hot.  Other than these things, it's possible that the wireless chip in the router is going bad.

Comment: So you think it's the router's fault, then? Even though all other devices work just fine? Interesting. I will try changing those settings tomorrow, but I'm sure it's not overheating.

Comment: About that last paragraf of answer, he wrote that with other notebook it just works, so we can exclude problems like router is overheating... I would try to switch in network card preferences, on that hp, wifi type to `G` and disable `N`

Comment: @week - what do you mean by wifi type? How do I set/disable that?

Comment: On keyboard -> Win + R, and start `ncpa.cpl`, then select your wifi adapter, mouse right click and select `preferences`, then select `configuration...`, than on 2nd tab find something like `802.11n mode` or `mode n`, select and disable it, then accept by ok and try to connect..

Comment: Whoa! Hugely bad advice about the channels! The channels *overlap*. If you use channel 3, you overlap both 1 *and* 6, making things much worse for everyone. When two networks are on the same channel, they can see and avoid each other. If they're on overlapping channels, they can't and step on each other horribly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I can't find anywhere that suggests it's better to have multiple access points on one channel, than it is to distance from those channels as much as possible.  There will almost always be overlap.  The only time there won't be is if you have, at most, 3 wireless routers on channels 1, 6, and 11.  In almost any residential neighborhood, there is overlap.  Networks will try to SHARE capacity on the same channel but it dramatically reduces performance.

Comment: @week - I couldn't find anything about a `802.11n mode` or `mode n`. Anyway, I've added more information to my post, please have a look at it.

Comment: @trpt4him: If two access points are both on channel 1, then they will try to share capacity. Yes, that reduces performance, but not as much as if they couldn't share capacity and just stepped on each other randomly. Yet that's what happens if one access point is on channel 1 and one on channel 3, because those channels overlap incompletely. It's even worse if there are access points on 1 and 6 and you put one on 3 -- now *two* access points randomly step on you, and you can't coordinate with either. Your advice is the opposite of the advice everyone else gives, including Cisco and Netgear.

Comment: Try to look at your wifi router firmware version, http://www.sitecom.com/support-product/productid/916#drivers , if it's your router at this link and you have earlier version, then upgrade.

Comment: Glad this is resolved, but I need to comment on this since I was downvoted for it and for the benefit of others.

From the Cisco web site: "A lot of wireless products in the US are shipped with a default channel of 6 like the Cisco Small Business router. If you encounter interference from other devices, change channels in order to get around these interferences." http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10024/products_qanda_item09186a0080a3562c.shtml

and from Netgear: "(lost connections) If this happens, you might need to experiment with different channels to see which is the best."

Comment: Please just remove the false statement, "Channels 1, 6, and 11 are the most commonly used so it's better to distance yourself from those." You *can't* distance yourself from those, because those cover the entire spectrum and WiFi handles partial overlap *much* worse than full overlap.

Comment: I have seen nothing that says that all wireless devices, especially consumer-level, handle full overlap better.  Besides, in real-life applications, the spectrum is so saturated in many neighborhoods that you're going to have partial overlap either way.  I merely suggested he try different channels.